# Show phones default language in overflow menu

Tags: android

I need to develop a page in android whose action overflow menu shows its default language in menu.How can i implement??
Now It displys its menu in Action bar;s overflow menu. But dont knw how and where to write the code for showing default language?? Is we write it in menu.xml?? or its on click???Please help...

```
String defaultLang = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
    txtDefaultLang = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDefaultLanguage);
    txtDefaultLang.setText(defaultLang);
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the menu code? (NOT the xml part)

you can use menu.setTitle() maybe..

Comment: menu folder resides under "res" folder